# How to Make a Flexible Subassembly with Top-Down Design Method in SOLIDWORKS?

Tags: solidworks

Recently, I'm trying to create a "4 dof robotic arm" on a robotic vehicle. The file structure be like:

- `Robotic.SLDASM`

  - `Vehicle Body.SLDASM`
  - `Robotic Arm.SLDASM`

    - `Gripper.SLDASM`

While I making `Robotic Arm` to be flexible subassembly in `Robotic`. SOLIDWORKS give me `subassemblies with layout sketches must be kept rigid`. After googling the solution. I only got that I need to delete the layout. That means I have to mate all the components in `Robotic Arm` again and lost advantage from Top-Down Design. Is there an alternative way to do the Top-Down Design and keep subassembly flexible? Is my file structure bad? Or my understanding is somewhere wrong?

Comment: There’s lots of ways to do this, but they are all easier at the start of the design rather than after you have invested time into your process. How far in are you and how many mates are we talking about?

Comment: Try going in the feature tree, right click on the Robotic Arm, click "Make Subassembly Flexible". That might solve your issue.

Comment: ^@jko this is what he's already tried, but because he defined the parts in context within the sub assembly using the layout function, this isn't an option.

Comment: Duh my bad. Not enough caffeine

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thanks for your reply. I don't mind to redo this design. I'm just a beginner of SOLIDWORKS.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Could you please give me some suggestions about the way to do this? I still have no idea.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to format a detailed answer yet! Summary: One way is to have a master skeleton part file which contains your layout sketches, and then mate things to that when designing top down, and then have a configuration where those mates are suppressed. A rigid and flexible configuration of the subassembly. Then just add the flexible one to the main assembly. Insert this part as the first feature in every component you create, and you can then use its geometry directly to define parts too

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thanks a lot! I've never think about using configuration. Incredible Answer!